# How to avoid type auto replace?

Tags: reactjs, flowtype, visual-studio-code

I'm using Flow types for props in React components. When I'm trying to write something like this:

```js
type Props = {
  someArray: Array<number>,
  someBoolean: boolean,
```

Right after I type last comma, it automatically replaces `boolean` with `Boolean` from capital letter. Since I need to use primitive here instead of wrapper class, I have to rewrite that letter. However it happens every time, so becoming really irritating.

I suppose that it can be fixed in settings, but I could find only suggestions-related options but not about auto replacing. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your VS code `settings.json` you can change `editor.acceptSuggestionOnCommitCharacter` to `false` and it would then work

[image: Working fine]

Comment: Great, thanks! That's exactly what I was looking for! I'll send bounty to you as soon it will be possible. This setting was almost obvious, but for some reason I missed it